# The class of grammars recognizable by backtracking recursive-descent parsers

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata, parsers, backtracking

It is easy to show that there exists a grammar that can be parsed by a recursive-descent parser with backtracking but is not an $\text{LL}(k)$ grammar (consider any grammar with a production featuring two alternatives starting with $k$ occurrences of the same terminal).

My question is the following: Is there an identifiable strict superset of $\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \text{LL}(k)$ grammars that can be parsed by a backtracking recursive-descent parser, regardless of complexity?

If yes, is the maximal superset also identifiable?

Comment: By any chance, do you mean [LL(*)](https://www.antlr.org/papers/LL-star-PLDI11.pdf)?

Comment: Any deterministic grammar can be parsed by an LL parser with backtracking, although it could take exponential time if you don't do a clever implementation. That's not a maximal superset, though

Comment: @Dmitry having a peek into the paper $\text{LL}(\star)$ would indeed qualify for the strict superset, thank you.

Comment: @rici Would you be able to point me to an example grammar that is not deterministic but parsable with a backtracking parser?